# Append multiple json request as list

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe, request

I can't seems to wrap my head around this silly issue. There are API requests that run simultaneously 23 different `section` stored in a dictionary :

```
polygonsDict = {
  'Sect1':'100,6.3',
  'Sect2':'100,6.0',
  'Sect3':'100,5.5' # and more sections
}

urlDict = {
  'traffic': 'https://google.com'
}
```

Here is the code where I iteratively :

```
section_key = list(polygonsDict.keys()) #convert the dictionary key to list for iteration

for idx, section in enumerate(section_key):
    traffics(section ,urlDict['traffic']+polygonsDict[section]).getPolygonTraffics() #This line is constructing the link for request.
```

Then, the link is send to a class called `traffics` with `getPolygonTraffics` function :

```
class traffics:
    def __init__(self, name, traffics):
        self.traffics = traffics
        self.name = name
    
    def getPolygonTraffics(self):

        try :
            print("TRF: Running for "+self.name+"...")
            raw = req.get(self.traffics).json()

            traffics_raw = [raw] #wrap the dict to list

            traffics_ls = []
            for ls in traffics_raw:

                traffics_ls.append(ls)

            #Melt the list of dictionary to form a DataFrame    
            traffics_df = pd.DataFrame(traffics_ls).explode('jams').reset_index(drop=True)
            print(traffics_df)

        #exception when `jams` is not found in the list of dict.
        except KeyError:
            print("Skip!")
```

In `getPolygonTraffics`, I want to append every `traffics_raw` (the json requests) to one individual list and eventually, `explode` them to a dataFrame. How can I achieve this? I'm not very sure how to explain this.

Current output is multiple lists of each dictionary :
[{}]
[{}]

WHat I want is : [{},{},{}]. Then `explode` to DataFrame.

Comment: use extend `traffics_ls.extend(ls)` or `traffics_ls += ls` and why are you converting dictionary to list it will only give list of keys? what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()` if you never use `idx`?

Comment: Just use `for section, polygon in polygonsDict.items():`

Comment: okay noted @Barmar

Comment: Don't you need a `/` between `urlDict['traffic']` and `polygonsDict[section]`? Otherwise you'll try to use a URL like `google.comSect1` instead of `google.com/Sect1`

Comment: @Barmar, I have more than one Url. Hence, I made the dictionary. This is not the problem I'm asking and they're working fine.

Comment: @komatiraju032 thanks! but none are working in my case

Comment: I want to append all requests into one dataframe. in order to use `explode` function, it has to be in list @komatiraju032. The problem is the requests are coming simultaneously and I need to append everytime.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `raw` into a list?

Comment: The `for` loop is just making a copy of `traffics_raw`. And `traffics_raw` is just a list of one element. Why all these lists?

Comment: Can you show an example of the API response and what you're trying to put into the df?